# How to update the value of field of from view when update the field of tree view?

Tags: view, onchange, odoo-8

How to update the value of field of from view when update the field of tree view?

I want to change the value of "total_location_qty" when I update the value of "location_qty".

This is my obj

```python
class Demo(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'demo.parent'

    demo_lines_ids = fields.One2many('demo.lines', 'demo_id', 'demo Items')
    total_location_qty = fields.Float(string='Total of location qty')


class DemoLines(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "demo.lines"

    demo_id = fields.Many2one('demo.parent', 'Demo')
    location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', 'Stock Location', readonly=True)
    location_qty = fields.Float(string='Location Qty')

    @api.onchange('location_qty')
    def on_change_location_qty(self):
        self.demo_id.total_location_qty = self.location_qty
```

This is my view

```xml
<record id="view_demo_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Demo</field>
        <field name="model">demo.parent</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Demo Parent">
        <group string="Demo">
        <group colspan="4">
                    <field name="total_location_qty" readonly="1"/>
                </group>
        <field name="demo_lines_ids" nolabel="1"   >
            <tree string="Demo Lines" editable="bottom" create="false" delete="false" >
            <field name="location_qty"/>
            </tree>
                 </field>
             </group>
        </form>
        </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Try with the `@api.one` decorator as well, with both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follow

Reference : account/account_invoice.py (Accounting -> Customer invoice or Customer Refund or Supplier refund)

```
class Demo(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'demo.parent'

    @api.one
    @api.depends('manual_pick_lines_ids.qty_pick_base_uom')
    def _compute_total_amount(self):
        self.total_amount = sum(line.line_total_amount for line in self.demo_lines_ids)

    demo_lines_ids = fields.One2many('demo.lines', 'demo_id', 'demo Items')
    total_amount = fields.Float(string='Total Amount', store=True, compute='_compute_total_amount')


class DemoLines(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "demo.lines"

    @api.one
    @api.depends('price', 'qty')
    def _compute_amount(self):
        self.line_total_amount = self.qty * self.price

    demo_id = fields.Many2one('demo.parent', 'Demo')
    location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', 'Stock Location', readonly=True)
    qty = fields.Float(string='Qty')
    price = fields.Float(string='Price')
    line_total_amount = fields.Float(string='Location Qty', compute='_compute_amount', store=True)
```